# Is Task<T>.await() main-safe?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm writing my first Kotlin app and am using firebase services for auth, db & storage. As it is not possible to make an atomic Firestore + Storage operation, I find myself in quit a callback-hell for a simple image upload (with error fallbacks and all). Thus - I decided to refactor my app to use coroutines. I found some examples (like [here](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-use-kotlin-coroutines-with-firebase-6f8577a3e00f) and [here](https://joebirch.co/android/using-firebase-on-android-with-kotlin-coroutines/)) but I noticed that the repository-level functions in those examples are not wrapped with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ }` like shown in [android docs](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines#use-coroutines-for-main-safety). Should they? I guess this is two questions in one:

1. Should Firebase operations always be called with the IO dispatcher?
2. Is `kotlinx-coroutines-play-services`'s `Task<T>.await()` main-safe?

And a bonus question: I wrap all my Firebase calls in a proxy object for decoupling - is there a way to set all functions of an object (/class) to run with the same context, or do I have to wrap each function with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ }` separately?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: By convention, all suspend functions are main-safe. It’s possible to compose one that isn’t, but if these await() functions are not, it would be an error on the part of the library author. `withContext` is for calling non-suspend blocking functions.

Comment: So I would say that by the same convention I would have to write all my functions main-safe as a good practice, right? The way to do that is by wrapping each function with `withContext(Dispatchers.xxx)`, or am I misunderstanding the use of that?

Comment: Use `withContext` inside coroutines and suspend functions to call blocking functions (functions that don’t return immediately and are not suspend functions), or to call a function that requires being called on the main thread when you are currently not on the main dispatcher. Suspend functions by convention are never blocking.

Comment: Your suspend functions definitely should all be main safe. If you’re fully committed to using coroutines, then yes, you’d probably convert any blocking functions in your own code into non-blocking suspend functions, and they would therefore be main-safe.

Comment: I think I'll now convert all my repository functions to be suspend functions. Is there a way to set a context to all functions of an object?

Comment: No, there isn't

Answer (score 5):

> 1. Should Firebase operations always be called with the IO dispatcher?

All Firebase APIs are asynchronous and designed to be called safely from the main thread unless otherwise stated in the API documentation.

> 2. Is kotlinx-coroutines-play-services's Task.await() main-safe?

Yes.  As the [API documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/com.google.android.gms.tasks.-task/await.html) states (emphasis mine):

> Awaits for completion of the task *without blocking a thread*.

It's a `suspend fun`, and they do not block.  However, they do not really make sense to call outside of a coroutine.

Comment: So does it matter which dispatcher I run those operations with? It doesn't count as a network call?

Comment: Why would it matter?  If you have concerns, see the API documentation for each individual call to understand its requirements.  I can't imagine you would have a problem unless there is some documentation that suggests otherwise.

Comment: `It doesn't count as a network call?` I think here you're implying the fallacy that "all network calls must be done within the IO dispatcher". Actually, all _blocking_ calls (network or otherwise) must be done on some dispatcher different from `Main` (IO is not strictly required), and a `suspend fun` is either non-blocking or has a serious bug that makes it block the calling thread. You can safely assume that all `suspend fun`s in a public library are compliant.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, it's customary to upvote and mark helpful answers as correct using the buttons to the left of the answer.